# Can I disable/set a display in Xorg?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I need to disable a display (eDP1) so it no longer displays and 
Set (HDMI1) as primary.

xrandr will not work as a perminant solution

I wrote a Xorg.conf file to change my resolution to 4k already and would like to add onto this one if I can.

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "Monitor0"
   Modeline "3840x2160_30.0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "Device0"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "Screen0"
   Device "Device0"
   Option "HDMI1"
   Monitor "Monitor0"
   DefaultDepth 24
   SubSection "Display"
      Depth 24
      Modes "3840x2160" "1920x1080"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I had to use Xrandr commands and leave them in an upstart file. (since xrandr is flaky on ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an upstart script and pasted xrandr commands in so it did it when my application opened

```
start on desktop-start
stop on runlevel [!2345]

pre-start script
    application_folder="$HOME/my/path"
    if [ ! -d "$application_folder" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$application_folder"
    fi

    xset s off         # don't activate screensaver
    xset -dpms         # disable DPMS (Energy Star) features.
    xset s noblank     # don't blank the video device
    xrandr --output eDP1 --off
    xrandr --output HDMI1 --primary

end script
```

you may also need to insert the command `export DISPLAY=:0` ontop of `xrandr` commands

Comment: Interesting script +1. Do you have a link to a guide where you learned the `xset` commands?